# Is the word "simpel" negative or positive?

Tags: meaning, connotation, difference

I am planning to use the word *simpel* in my technology product. I have found two contrasting definitions on the web:

- simple, easy to use
- stupid, dumb

What is the more popular meaning of the word? Is it more positive or negative?

Comment: Words aren't positive or negative. People may prefer them in one context but not the other, but often they won't agree.

Comment: @user: language always happens in the context of people. If many people attach some positive or negative feelings to words, then that *is* important.

Comment: Attaching some positive or negative feelings to words, is not important - it's the wrong way to use language. If somebody produces negative feelings when hearing the word 'ill', and I tell him "I'm not ill anymore", he simply reacts wrong. We shouldn't behave like Pawlovs dog, and shouldn't excuse such behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

When used for a technology product the usage of *"simpel"* is not appropriate. Indeed it does have the subtle meaning of something to be very easy on one hand but on the other hand also to be not so sophisticated.

In the context of technology use e.g.:

> es ist *einfach* zu bedienen  (*simple*)
>
> es ist *leicht* zu bedienen (*easy*)
>
> es ist *nicht schwer* zusammenzubauen (*not hard*)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.The aim of the product is "to be so easy to use that it feels natural".

Comment: You could say e.g.: *"Das Produkt ist **einfach und intuitiv** zu bedienen"* or *"... ist **kinderleicht** zu bedienen"*.

Comment: I think it's wrong to directly associate `simple` with `einfach` and `easy` with `leicht`. I'd consider the two synonymous in this context.

Comment: they are synonyms like *simple* and *easy* are - it's more a  tendency (*leicht* does not quite translate to *simple* - where *easy* works better)

Comment: Yes, you may be right about the tendency, but then again, the tendency is about different contexts. In this context here, you could just as well reverse the associations: "It's simple to use" -> "Es ist leicht zu bedienen." works just as well. I do realize I may be nitpicking here, I just thought your reply was suggesting something that doesn't really apply here.

Comment: Your comment is perfectly right here - both versions work the same and it does depend very much on the context whatever may be slightly better (or not).

Comment: If you say »Die Bedienung ist *simpel*«, the meaning is not negative either.

Answer (score 6):

Both meanings are popular, but I can't think of a situation in which a) is intended and b) is understood. So the problem is not a possible misunderstanding.

However, to my ears, "simpel" does not sound like a word you want to have in an operating manual. It's not colloquial, but somehow a little blunt (can't find a better way to describe it). The standard word is "einfach", it has the meaning a) and sounds a lot better (at least in written text).

Comment: "einfach" *can* have traces of meaning b) as well, but it's a lot rarer than with "simpel" and not as strong. "Er ist ein bisschen einfach."